# connect to Oracle db with JDBC driver. How set charSet?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, character-encoding

I need connect to Oracle database use jdbc driver. I look on structure URL string to connect and not see, where i xan set charSet to connect. 
Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to set the character set.  Java uses Unicode internally and the data from the database should be converted from the database character set to UTF-16 by the JDBC driver.

Comment: i connect to database use THIN driver and in result i have string: ?????????? on server Oracle database charSet cp1251.

Comment: In most of the cases I have encountered this, the values were already stored incorrectly in the database. In some cases the output was wrong (e.g. a console that couldn't print the characters, wrong encoding in the HTML/JSP pages), but it had never to do with "setting a charset" on the client, especially not with the thin driver.

Comment: The situation has cleared up a bit: i have ???? in error messages.perhaps this is an important information.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, many years leaved, but I have the same situation. Yes, may be strings in the database are saved wrong, but it's not a problem with manual set client's encoding (by set environment NLS_LANG, for example) using many other oracle clients. Except jdbc!

And the question is: Is any way to solve this problem in client-side using jdbc client with this kind of oracle databases, where strings are already stored with forced wrong client's encoding?